# gnu linker doesn't include unreferenced modules in a shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I have a shared library that consists of quite a few .c modules, some of which are themselves linked into the shared library from other static .a libraries.  Most of these are referenced internally within the library, but some are not.  I'm finding that the linker does not include those modules in the shared library unless there is at least one call to a function in the module from within the shared library.  I've been working around this problem by adding calls in a dummy ForceLinkages() function in a module that I know will be included.

That's okay, but it's surprising, since I'm using a .version file to define a public API to this library.  I would've thought including functions in those unreferenced .c modules in the .version file would constitute a reference to the modules and force them to be included in the library.

This library was originally developed on AIX, which uses a .exp file to define the public API.  And there, I've never had the issue of unreferenced modules not getting included.  I.e., referencing the modules in the .exp file was enough to get the linker to pull them in.  Is there a way to get the linux linker to work like that.  If not, I can continue to use my silly ForceLinkages() function to get the job done...

Comment: `__attribute__((__used__))`. Please share how do you create those shared libraries, how do you compile those .c files, how do you create the static libraries.

Comment: Nothing special.  Building the library with a bunch of .o modules and a bunch of .a libraries (containing .o modules).  Here are the relevant linker options:                                                   
     -Wl,--version-script=/home/rob/em/emapp/shlibemapp.version -shared -fPIC -Xlinker --cref -Xlinker -Map=shlibemapp.map

Comment: It would be the `--whole-archive` option of `ld`.

Comment: " I would've thought including functions in those unreferenced .c modules in the .version file would constitute a reference to the modules" - this makes a lot of sense, have you considered raising this in https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/ ?

Comment: It sounds like --whole-archive might do the trick, but in a brute force kind of way.  I didn't say I wanted *every* module in the archive included - just the ones that are referenced.  And that inclusion in the .version file ought to qualify as a reference.  But that said, this is a single shared library, and having it be a little bigger than necessary wouldn't be the end of the world.  But for now, I'm okay with adding stuff to my ForcedLinkages() function whenever an app fails to link against the library.  But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That's okay, but it's surprising, since I'm using a .version file to define a public API to this library.

The `.version` file (assuming it's a linker version script) does not *define* the library API. If only determines which functions are *exported* from the library (and with which version label) and which are hidden.

> I would've thought including functions in those unreferenced .c modules in the .version file would constitute a reference to the modules and force them to be included in the library.

The version script is applied *after* the linker has decided which objects are going to be part of the library, and which are going to be discarded, and has no effect on the decisions taken earlier.

This is all working as designed.

You need to either use `--whole-archive` `--no-whole-archive` (this has a danger of linking in code you don't need and bloating your binaries), or keep adding references as you've done before.